# Install own R package

Tags: r, installation, package, local

I want to install a local package.
I tried:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Name/Dropbox...Rpackage/", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

which results in:

```
Warning: invalid package 'C:/Users/Name/Dropbox...Rpackage/'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Name/Dropbox...Rpackage/’ had non-zero exit status
```

I will be thankful for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your call to `install.packages()` is incorrect. If you are trying to install a local development package from its source directory (i.e. the folder containing DESCRIPTION, NAMESPACE, R/, etc.) you can either:

- Navigate to the folder and run devtools::install() or `R CMD INSTALL` from a terminal.
- Utilize [`remotes::install_local()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/remotes/man/install_local.html#:%7E:text=install_local%3A%20Install%20a%20package%20from%20a%20local%20file,Usage%20Arguments%20See%20Also%20Examples%20View%20source%3A%20R%2Finstall-local.R) pointing to the directory.